# Add, View, Update, and Delete Student Record using Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, oop, menu

i need help with my code. I am stuck at 2 (View student record), we only allowed to use arrays and not arraylist or linked list. Any advice and help will do.

Heres the instructions:
Write a menu driven program that performs the following:

1.Add record
- can add N students record into the list (ID num, name, course, year)

2.View record
- can view record by ID number, by course, by course and year
- or view all

3.Update record
- can edit/modify the records attribute excluding the ID

4.Delete
- can remove student record

Heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentArray {

public static void main(String[] args){

    getMenu();

}
public static void getMenu( ){
    Student[] stud = new Student[100];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int select;
    System.out.println("1. Add Student Record");
    System.out.println("2. View Student Record");
    System.out.println("3. Update Student Record");
    System.out.println("4. Delete Student Record");
    System.out.println("0. Exit");
    select = sc.nextInt();

    switch (select){
        case 1:
            addStud(stud);
            getMenu();
            break;
        case 2:
            viewStud(stud);
            getMenu();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
    }

}
public static void addStud(Student[] stud){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int numID, year;
     String userName, course;

    int addMore;
    int i = 0;
    do{

        System.out.println("1. Enter Student ID: ");
         numID = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("2. Enter Student Name");
         userName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("3. Enter Student Course");
         course = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("4. Enter Student Year");
         year = sc.nextInt();
         stud[i] = new Student(numID, year, userName, course);
        ++i;

        System.out.println("To add another Student Record Press 1");
        addMore = sc.nextInt();
    }while (addMore == 1 );

}
public static void viewStud(Student[] stud){
    for(int x = 0; x < stud.length ; ++x){
        System.out.println("1. Student ID: " + stud[x].getNumID());
        System.out.println("2. Student Name: " + stud[x].getUserName());
        System.out.println("3. Student Course: " + stud[x].getCourse());
        System.out.println("4. Student Year: " + stud[x].getYear() + "\n");
    }

}
}
```

My Student Class:

```
public class Student {

private int numID, year;
private String userName, course;

public Student(int numID, int year, String userName, String course) {

    this.numID = numID;
    this.year = year;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.course = course;

}


public int getNumID() {
    return numID;
}

public void setNumID(int numID) {
    this.numID = numID;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(String course) {
    this.course = course;
}

}
```

Hello thank you SNJ,

I remove my getMenu method and put the code in the main instead.But I'm unable to set the Student array and i to static

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class StudentArray {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        static Student[] stud = new Student[100];
        static int i = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {

            int select;
            System.out.println("1. Add Student Record");
            System.out.println("2. View Student Record");
            System.out.println("3. Update Student Record");
            System.out.println("4. Delete Student Record");
            System.out.println("0. Exit");
            select = sc.nextInt();

            switch (select) {
                case 1:
                    addStud(stud);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewStud(stud);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 0:
                    return;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Option");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void addStud(Student[] stud) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numID, year;
        String userName, course;

        int addMore;

        do {

            System.out.println("1. Enter Student ID: ");
            numID = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("2. Enter Student Name");
            userName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("3. Enter Student Course");
            course = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("4. Enter Student Year");
            year = sc.nextInt();
            stud[i] = new Student(numID, year, userName, course);
            ++i;

            System.out.println("To add another Student Record Press 1");
            addMore = sc.nextInt();
        } while (addMore == 1);

    }

    public static void viewStud(Student[] stud) {

        for (Student element : stud) {
            if (null != element) {
                System.out.println("1. Student ID: " + element.getNumID());
                System.out.println("2. Student Name: " + element.getUserName());
                System.out.println("3. Student Course: " + element.getCourse());
                System.out.println("4. Student Year: " + element.getYear() + "\n");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Small remark, I wouldn't use recursion (calling your getMenu() method). Since Java is not tail recursive, we could end up in a stackoverflow. Use a while(true) loop and use a break statement if the input value is equal to "0".

Comment: what specific problem are you facing?

Comment: My addStudent method is working but when i try to view them i got the following error on intelliJ:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at StudentArray.viewStud(StudentArray.java:69)
 at StudentArray.getMenu(StudentArray.java:28)
 at StudentArray.getMenu(StudentArray.java:25)
 at StudentArray.main(StudentArray.java:7)

I think maybe of using getMenu() instead of looping?

Comment: I kind of think this is too much to be a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loosing student value in between method calls.If you make Student array and i as static, it will retain your values between method calls.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentArray {

public static void main(String[] args){

static Student[] stud = new Student[100];
    static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    getMenu();

    }

    public static void getMenu() {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {

        int select;
        System.out.println("1. Add Student Record");
        System.out.println("2. View Student Record");
        System.out.println("3. Update Student Record");
        System.out.println("4. Delete Student Record");
        System.out.println("0. Exit");
        select = sc.nextInt();

        switch (select) {
        case 1:
        addStud(stud);

        break;
        case 2:
        viewStud(stud);

        break;
        case 3:
        break;
        case 4:
        break;
        case 0:
        return;
        default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Option");
        }
    }

    }

    public static void addStud(Student[] stud) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numID, year;
    String userName, course;

    int addMore;

    do {

        System.out.println("1. Enter Student ID: ");
        numID = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("2. Enter Student Name");
        userName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("3. Enter Student Course");
        course = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("4. Enter Student Year");
        year = sc.nextInt();
        stud[i] = new Student(numID, year, userName, course);
        ++i;

        System.out.println("To add another Student Record Press 1");
        addMore = sc.nextInt();
    } while (addMore == 1);

    }

    public static void viewStud(Student[] stud) {

    for (Student element : stud) {
        if (null != element) {
        System.out.println("1. Student ID: " + element.getNumID());
        System.out.println("2. Student Name: " + element.getUserName());
        System.out.println("3. Student Course: " + element.getCourse());
        System.out.println("4. Student Year: " + element.getYear() + "\n");
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Hello thank you,

I remove my getMenu method and put the code in the main instead.

,,,

Comment: If the answer solve your problem. Please don't hesitate to accept the answer